# Tidying data correctly with pivot table- leaving index as a two-level

Tags: python, pandas, pivot

I am struggling to solve this problem. I known how to produce a pivot table, but I am really struggling with keeping the index as a two-level. Here is the question and my code is below that:

Use `pivot_table` to tidy the data below in `table1`, assigning the result to the variable `table1_tidy`.  In this case, leave the index as the two-level `country` and `year`.

```
table1columns = ["country",  "year",       "type",     "count"]
table1data =[ ["Afghanistan",  1999,      "cases",       745],
          ["Afghanistan",  1999, "population",  19987071],
          ["Afghanistan",  2000,      "cases",      2666],
          ["Afghanistan",  2000, "population",  20595360],
          [     "Brazil",  1999,      "cases",     37737],
          [     "Brazil",  1999, "population", 172006362],
          [     "Brazil",  2000,      "cases",     80488],
          [     "Brazil",  2000, "population", 174504898],
          [      "China",  1999,      "cases",    212258],
          [      "China",  1999, "population",1272915272],
          [      "China",  2000,      "cases",    213766],
          [      "China",  2000, "population",1280428583] ]

table1 = pd.DataFrame(table1data, columns=table1columns)

### BEGIN SOLUTION
'''
This code uses `pivot_table` to tidy the data below in `table1`, 
assigning the result to the variable `table1_tidy`.
'''
table1_tidy = table1.pivot('type', 'count')
### END SOLUTION
# When done, comment out line below
# raise NotImplementedError()
print(table1_tidy)
```

My code needs to pass the following assert statements, but is currently failing to do so:

```
assert table1_tidy.shape == (6, 2)
assert table1_tidy.iloc[3, 0] == 80488
```

Answer (score 1):

Pivot gives value error for multi index indexing. There is an open bug on [GitHub](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/21425) for the same. Current solution is to use pivot_table instead

```
table1_tidy = table1.pivot_table( index = ['country', 'year'], columns = 'type',values = 'count')



type                cases   population
country     year        
Afghanistan 1999    745     19987071
            2000    2666    20595360
Brazil      1999    37737   172006362
            2000    80488   174504898
China       1999    212258  1272915272
            2000    213766  1280428583
```

You can get the same result using set_index

```
table1_tidy = table1.set_index(['country', 'year', 'type'])['count'].unstack()
```